# VxWorks: Why bootline can't be changed？

Tags: embedded, ram, boot, vxworks

I am trying to revise the bootline of VxWorks by running the “bootChange” command in shell.

I can successfully see the change right after i run this command by checking “version” command, but when i really try rebooting the VxWork, the changes wasn't applied.

So i am confused and hope i can get some insight of why such change doesn't work.

By the way there does have a flash as the main storage in my equipment, and i believe the bootrom image which contains the booline was burned in that flash.

And i have checked that the flash wasn't mounted in VxWorks by running “devs” command.

Comment: Seems like your question is missing your commands and your configuration setup as such we can't help you and this question is going to be closed

Comment: You need to go through BSP source files.

Answer (score 0):

Is your system booting with U-Boot or with a VxWorks Bootrom?
You might confirm which VxWorks version is used.

If you have a bootrom, try the to change the boot line parameter from the bootrom context by using the command "c".
You can also pass the full boot line parameter preceded with "$" to tell to the boron to use this boot line instead.

Note: devs in VxWorks would not display the flash/nvram being used for storing the boot line parameter. You might check the file target.nr, target.ref in the BSP directory.